# Write c# array to aspx html page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I take my C# array and write it to an HTML table header?

From what I've read you should be able to use cnippets to get the variable but it's not working...

**C# code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] tableHeaders = {
                "Urgency", 
                "Picker", 
                "CARD", 
                "Case Order", 
                "CR #", 
                "Patient", 
                "Age", 
                "ASA", 
                "Anes Consult", 
                "Procedure", 
                "Booking Surgeon", 
                "Operating Surgeon", 
                "Ready Date", 
                "Ready Time", 
                "NPO Since", 
                "EST Time", 
                "Current Location", 
                "Postop Need", 
                "Booked by", 
                "Special Equipment", 
                "Comments"
            };
        }
```

**HTML Code**
You'll see in my document.write line I try to call the tableHeaders variable. And I use the javascript row variable as a counter.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      for (var row = 0; row <= 21; row++) {
        document.write("+<%= tableHeaders[+row+] %>+")
      }
    </script>
   </tr>
 </thead>
```

Comment: Make tableheaders a global property

Comment: Are you trying to create dynamic `<th>` elements in your row or just write out a list of header names?

Comment: Yes. I've just been told that you can't put C# variables in java-script so that kind of means my question isn't valid.

Comment: @Frantumn: I wouldn't say your question isn't valid as much as your attempted solution won't get the job done as you've envisioned it. Though an edit to the question might make it a little more clear.

Comment: Maybe you want to use [`RegisterArrayDeclaration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn't have been trying to use Java-script to do this. The following worked perfectly.

```
 <%
     for (int td = 0; td <= 20; td++)
     {
         Response.Write("<td>" + tableHeaders[td] + "</td>");
     }
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a *local* variable in `Page_Load` then trying to access it from the page script.  You can make it a class member instead:

(outside of `Page_Load` or any other method):

```
private string[] tableHeaders = {
    "Urgency", 
    "Picker", 
    "CARD", 
    "Case Order", 
    "CR #", 
    "Patient", 
    "Age", 
    "ASA", 
    "Anes Consult", 
    "Procedure", 
    "Booking Surgeon", 
    "Operating Surgeon", 
    "Ready Date", 
    "Ready Time", 
    "NPO Since", 
    "EST Time", 
    "Current Location", 
    "Postop Need", 
    "Booked by", 
    "Special Equipment", 
    "Comments"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to create actual header cells for your table, you should be able to do it all within c# code behind unless you have some need to dump things into JavaScript. Add an ID to your `<tr>` element and a runat attribute:

```
<thead>
    <tr ID="headerRow" runat="server">
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Then in your page load you can add each header element individually:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] tableHeaders = { // blah blah };

    foreach(var header in tableHeaders)
    {
        var tmp = new TableHeaderCell();
        tmp.ID = "TH_" + header;
        tmp.Text = header;
        headerRow.Cells.Add(tmp);
    }
}
```

Then when the page renders, it should render each one out as a `<th>` element within your row.

Comment: I like this answer, I get an error though. 
Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableHeaderCell' to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell' I probably need some using statements. (I'm still getting used to C#).

Comment: where does your variable headerRow come from ?

Comment: TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(); 
needs to be above your for each.

Comment: @Frantumn: No it doesn't. If you read the entire answer, you'll see that the `headerRow` is specified by the ID in the markup. That's why you need `runat="server"` as a part of the markup. Because `headerRow` is specified without any specific parent it should be available without using `FindControl("headerRow")`. If you have `runat="server"` specified on a parent element (such as table perhaps) then you would need to use `FindControl`.